# special grouping and listing of db query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to:

```
ID  |  NAME    |  GROUP_ID
1   | rand_str |  4
2   | rand_str |  2
3   | rand_str |  3
4   | rand_str |  0
5   | rand_str |  3
6   | rand_str |  1
7   | rand_str |  3
8   | rand_str |  3
9   | rand_str |  1
10  | rand_str |  0
```

ID is unique ID, name valie is not null and contains varchar value and group_id is a max 2 digit positive number.

Let's say that the query returns this table.

What I want is, using PHP, show the results grouped by their group_id and if possible, ordering the group id by the most numbered to least numbered and "0" being always the last no matter how populated it is.

so end result:

group id 3 exists 3 times, so

1. 1- id_3, id_5, id_7 and id_8 (group_id 3)
2. 2- id_6, id_9 (group_id 1)
3. 3- either group id 4 or 2 since both contain 1 item each
4. 4- group_id 0, even though it has 2 items -> id_4, id_10

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be much easier to do with a SQL query than PHP

Comment: @AaronW., I agree. However without PHP, it is not possible to print the results of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery to determine the count of each group (and therefore its order), then join that with your data to retrieve the records:

```sql
SELECT my_table.* FROM my_table JOIN (
  SELECT   GROUP_ID,
           IF(GROUP_ID = 0, -1, COUNT(*)) AS rank
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY GROUP_ID
) AS t USING (GROUP_ID)
ORDER BY t.rank DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67888/3).

You would then loop over the results in PHP, keeping track of the `GROUP_ID` of the last record and comparing with the current one to see whether you're now in a new group:

```
$last = null;
echo "<table>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  if ($row['GROUP_ID'] !== $last) {
    if ($last !== null) echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr><th scope='row'>Group " . html_entities($row['GROUP_ID']) . "</th>";
    $last = $row['GROUP_ID'];
  }
  echo "<td>ID " . html_entities($row['ID']) . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: I agree with you, seems the good way for me :) (but too lazy for writing it down)

Comment: @eggyal, thank you very much not only for the response but for also explaining it. I really appreciate it a lot. Great solution, so elegant. I want to quickly as one more thing: What exactly is '-1' of IF(GROUP_ID = 0, -1, COUNT(*))? How does this achieve making the group of 0 appear last?

Comment: @Phil: We define a result column called `order` which holds the number of items in each group unless the group_id is 0, in which case we set it to -1.  Then, when we sort our results in descending order by that column, since -1 will always be less than the number of results in any other group (including any groups containing no items) group_id 0 will always appear last.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look there : http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

You'll learn how to use Group By SQL Keyword :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you require using the folowing query

```
select group_concat(id),name, group_id, count(*) entries from grp
group by group_id
order by entries desc ;
```

Comment: That will not rank group 0 at the bottom unless it is the only group with the minimal number of members.